# React Native, with multiple root app, how to share reducer data?

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a separate root react native view for each activity (or viewController in iOS)

Each of them has a separate root reducer.

(eg.
MainActivity has React Native entry point and a root reducer
SearchActivity has another RN entry point and a root reducer
)

Now I have some data I fetch on application start, and want to use it on multiple RN apps, I'm thinking of storing the data in asyncstorage and pull and store the data in reducers at RN app start.

Wonder if there is alternative approach?

Comment: That's a very good question, I was wondering the same about sharing data between MainActivity and HeadlessJs contexts... My idea was to share Redux store through hydrate/persist. But this meant redux could be de-synchronized between contexts